# Compare list of JSONArray in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` containing a list of `JSONArray`s

```
staffArray = new ArrayList<JSONArray>();
```

the `JSONArray` is in a form of this:

```
[
    {
      "id": "k40dn-dff02-mm1",
      "name": "staff1",
      "tel": "0123456789",
    },
    {
      "id": "ch2mq-pmw01-ps6",
      "name": "staff2",
      "tel": "9876543210",
    }
    ...
]
```

And the `ArrayList` will be containing different sizes of `JSONArray`.
Now I want to check in the `ArrayList` for each `JSONArray`, if they contain the same value for "id". So say that if the `ArrayList` has three different sizes of `JSONArray`, how can I tell the they each contain a `JSONObject` with the same value for "id" in it.

So far I have tried this to extract the string:

```
for(int i = 0; i < staffArray.size(); i++){
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray = staffArray.get(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j ++){
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            String id = json.getString("id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to check for duplicate IDs in your `ArrayList`, you could do something like this:

```
ArrayList<JSONArray> staffArray = new ArrayList<>();

Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();
for (JSONArray array : staffArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        if (!ids.add(obj.getString("id"))) {
            // duplicate IDs found, do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what I want is to find duplicate in different JSONArrays, say that ArrayList contains three JSONArrays and check if each JSONArray has a key "id" with the same value

Comment: @JerryKo I see. You just have to move the `Set` of IDs outside the outer loop then. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using group by to group the json arrays with same id something like this

```
public static void groupById(List<JSONArray> staffArray) {
    Map<String, List<JSONArray>> jsonArraysById = staffArray.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(jsonArray -> getIdFromJsonArray(jsonArray)));
    jsonArraysById.forEach((id, arrays) -> {
        System.out.println("Arrays with id " + id + " are " + arrays);
    });
}

public static String getIdFromJsonArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    String result = null;
    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            result = json.getString("id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```